# Drag and drop issue with "Largest width limit dp"

Tags: android

Excuse my low level of english :(

I'm developing an Android app. Here are the SDK that I support:

Min SDK version: 13
Target SDK version: 16

I have also declared `supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"` in Manifest.xml.

I've implemented the drag and drop feature. All work fine if I test the app in a 320-density screen device (Nexus S, for instance) but the drag-and-drop fails if I test in a greatest-320-density screen device, such Note 3, or Nexus 5.

In that case, I'm able to drag the view but when I put the view over the target view, **there is a displacement**. I mean, **I'm able to do the "drop" only if I put the first view outside of the bounds of the target view**.

If I remove the `supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"` attribute, all work without problems. But, as you might guess, it is strictly necessary in my app.

You can check the project. [Download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mkXsoIIRVEZVZQaGFhLVNoM0E/edit?usp=sharing).

Please, check these photos to better understand what I mean:

**supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="320" OFF (all work fine)**
[(IMAGE LINK)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mkXsoIIRVEZjBiejJlZjZwRnM/edit?usp=sharing)

**supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="320" ON (you can see the issue: gray view is not YELLOW view)**
(IMAGE LINK drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mkXsoIIRVEb04zSmZmZ05SODQ/edit?usp=sharing)

**supports-screens android:largestWidthLimitDp="320" ON (ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED is active only on the "virtual" box [outside of the blue view bounds)**
(IMAGE LINK drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mkXsoIIRVEa3RGM1hPNjJCaTg/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm afraid this is a bug of Android OS. Assuming this attribute can't be put off, do you know a solution for this issue? Thank you very much for your help

**(EDIT)**

Sorry about the post format. I'm unable to submit for than 2 links.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation seems like the android:largestWidthLimitDp makes the app get into a compatibility mode if the value set is smaller than device's smallest width (nexus 5 has a "smallest screen width" of 360dp which is bigger). So the app is getting into this compatibility mode.

Also from the docs: "Currently the compatibility mode only emulates phone screens with a 320dp width"
meaning that your app thinks the layout width is as much of 320dp. Since the N5 is 360, I would assume that there are some problems with the calculations.

From the code I can't see any problem so this might be a problem somewhere else. Have you tried using the "draw view bounds" options in the developer settings?

However I would discourage the use of supports-screens and create a responsive design, the experience will be better.

Comment: "Draw view bounds", from developer settings, shows that all rects are ok placed over the views, so the collision rect isn't drawn.

I know I don't have to use supports-screens, but time is very limited right now. Anyway, thank you for the tip :-)